# VectorDrawable scale

Tags: android, vector, scale, drawable

Tell me please what is the correct way to write custom view which will draw vector drawable and support scaling. I tried like

> canvas.drawBitmap(image, drawMatrix, paint);

where drawMatrix is matrix with scale and translate values, but when scale is big image becomes poor quality as simple drawable. How should I scale Vector to save its quality. Thanks.